# Change textcolor with click on different button

Tags: swift, swift5

I have two `IBAction` and want to change of the text of two buttons who refer to these `IBActions`.
I can change with sender. the color of the own button. But not with the other button. How can I solve this? My Code doesnt work. It only changes the own color.

```
  @IBAction func arminiaBielefeld(_ sender: UIButton) {
    team = "arminia"
    Bundesliga1.bildlink =  "bundesliga1/arminia"
    Bundesliga1.ligaIcon =  "bundesliga1/bundesliga1"
    sender.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
    augsburg.setTitleColor(.blue, for: [])
}
@IBAction func augsburg(_ sender: UIButton) {
    team = "augsburg"
    Bundesliga1.bildlink =  "bundesliga1/augsburg"
    Bundesliga1.ligaIcon =  "bundesliga1/bundesliga1"
    sender.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
    arminiaBielefeld.setTitleColor(.blue, for: [])
}
```

[Screenshot added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bATsu.png)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code so it is impossible to help. You need to prove that your actions and outlets are correctly configured.

Comment: I'll add a Screenshot in a minute. I get two errors right now. 1. Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member blue 2. Value of type UIbutton has no member setTitleColor.

Comment: OK, so you should have pasted that code into the question. Do not show pictures of code. If you had done that, it would have been instantly obvious to us what the problem is, namely that you are using the terms `augsburg` and `arminiaBielefeld` but they do not refer to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the outlet name of the button instead of sender. Also do not have the name of the action identical to the name of the outlet.

Add the following two outlets to your view controller and connect them in storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet weak var arminiaBielefeld: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var augsburg: UIButton!
```

The following works:

```
@IBAction func arminiaBielefeldPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    team = "arminia"
    Bundesliga1.bildlink =  "bundesliga1/arminia"
    Bundesliga1.ligaIcon =  "bundesliga1/bundesliga1"
    arminiaBielefeld.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
    augsburg.setTitleColor(.blue, for: [])
}

@IBAction func augsburgPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    team = "augsburg"
    Bundesliga1.bildlink =  "bundesliga1/augsburg"
    Bundesliga1.ligaIcon =  "bundesliga1/bundesliga1"
    augsburg.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
    arminiaBielefeld.setTitleColor(.blue, for: [])
}
```